# Sort 2 different lists that both contains the same value by common value

Tags: python

I have to lists that looks like this:

```
list1 = [ ["name1", 100], ["name2", 33], ["name3", 22]]
list2 = [ ["name2", 1], ["name1", -1], ["name3", 0]]
```

The lists contains between `0` and `20` names

The names in both lists are exactly the same, but the integer values are different.

Is it possible to sort list2 so that the *order of the names* is the same as in list1?

The order of the names vary, so it must be a flexible solution that can sort the names no matter where they are placed in `list2`.

I want the output to look like this:
`list1 = [ ["name1", 100], ["name2", 33], ["name3", 22]]`

`list2 = [ ["name1", -1], ["name2", 1], ["name3", 0]]`

Comment: please quote those strings if they are strings, otherwise make `name1_int` etc. actually ints... thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new list, in the same order as `list2` that just contains the names. Then you can sort `list1` based on the first element in each list (the name)'s index in that `names` list:

```
names = [l[0] for l in list1]
list2.sort(key=lambda l: names.index(l[0]))
#[['name1', -1], ['name2', 1], ['name3', 0]]
```

Comment: This only sorts by the a  single index. i need it to index twice, as there are a list in a list. Is that possible?

Comment: @Barmar I have corrected the ans, sorry about that!

Comment: ValueError: ['name1', 100] is not in list
I receive this error when running the code

Comment: @JoeIddon It only need to sort by the name, not the whole list

Comment: @FlugtN Make sure you copy the list definitions exactly and the code exactly (it has been updated recently). I have just tested and it works.

Comment: @JoeIddon aaawww maan. Works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more optimal solution that works in `O(n)` time - it creates a dict out of the list2, so that the `.index` can be avoided, improving the complexity to `O(n)` from `O(n**2)`:

```
In [68]: list1 = [ ["name1", 100], ["name2", 33], ["name3", 22]]
    ...: list2 = [ ["name2", 1], ["name1", -1], ["name3", 0]]
    ...: 

In [69]: d_list2 = dict(list2)

In [70]: list2 = [[name, d_list2[name]] for (name, _) in list1]

In [71]: list2
Out[71]: [['name1', -1], ['name2', 1], ['name3', 0]]
```